# Normal and subnormal series

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a subnormal series of a finite group $G$ then is there any specific formula to find the order of $G$?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: The same one that works given any filtration.

Comment: Calculate all the intermediate indices and multiply them!

Comment: There is this formula I just found |G|=(product |Gi/Gi+1|)|Gn|. is this same think what Nicky said. and how can I see that formula is correct. can anyone give a little hint about that?

Comment: Yes. It's obvious using $|A/B|=|A|/|B|$ and telescopy (for example, $12=(12/4)(4/2)(2/1)$).